# error on per server prefixes command with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, discord, discord.py, pymongo

idk why but each time i try to set a new prefix it sends an error code im mad lost rn idk if it says 'Config' object has no attribute 'prefixes' i feel like i did some wrong with the mongodb part in the main file

prefix cog:

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
    async def prefix(self, ctx, prefix=None):
        if prefix is None:
            return await ctx.send("Put in a prefix for me to change to!")

        data = await self.bot.prefixes.find(ctx.guild.id)
        if data is None or "prefix" not in data:
            data = {"_id": ctx.guild.id, "prefix": prefix}
        data["prefix"] = prefix
        await self.bot.prefixes.upsert(data)
        await ctx.send("I have changed the server's prefix to {}".format(prefix))

    @commands.command(aliases=["dp"])
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
    async def deleteprefix(self,ctx):
        await self.bot.bot.prefixes.unset({"_id": ctx.guild.id, "prefix": 1})
        await ctx.send("The server's prefix has been set to default")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Config(bot))
```

error:

```
Ignoring exception in command prefix:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\...\Documents\fright\cogs\config.py", line 16, in prefix
    data = await self.prefixes.find(ctx.guild.id)
AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'prefixes'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'prefixes'
```

Comment: The error is calling out the `Config` object that is referenced in the `config.py` file.  You haven't shown either of those.

Comment: Could you provide a full code, please?

Comment: its too long so i ut it on a paste bin https://pastebin.com/Zzh3LsHc

Comment: fixed jus need to do a small change on the cog